# Performing automated function over many columns in R

Tags: r, matrix

Forgive me, I am very new to this. If someone could help or point me towards a resource to help, I'd be most appreciative:

I have a data table with 150,000 observations of 300 variables, some outcome/symptom (dependent variables) and some input (independent variables). For each symptom, I want descriptive statistics, and the results of a chi-squared test for association to each input.

For the descriptive statistics, I have managed to do this by making a matrix of the outcome variables called "symptom.matrix" and used "apply".

```
Desc.stats<-matrix(c(apply(symptom.matrix,2,sum),
                     apply(symptom.matrix,2,mean),
                     apply(symptom.matrix,2,function(x)
                           {return(sqrt((mean(x)*(1-mean(x)))/length(x)))})),
                  ncol=3,                                 
                  dimnames=list(c(...),
                  c("N","prev","s.e."))); Desc.stats
```

To get the chi square, I use the chisq.test on individual pairs of outcome and input in the following way, but I can't see how to apply this to the symptom.matrix

```
 result1<-(chisq.test(symptom1,input1));
print (c(result1$statistic, result1$p.value))
```

How do I scale this up to work over the symptom.matrix? Is it possible using the chisq.test, or would I be better off going back to basics to write a function for the statistics myself?

Comment: Please show how *symptoms* and *input* are identified in data table. Are they prefixed/suffixed? Maybe even show original dataset or post for us to run: `dput(head(mydatatable))`

Comment: _symptoms_ and _input_ aren't identified as such in the data table. So I called the symptoms from the data table thus: 'symptom.matrix<-with(mydatatable, matrix (c (Vision,Voice,Del,Paranoia,... ),ncol=8))'

Comment: And what about *inputs*?

Comment: Similarly, they are labelled mydatatable$Gender, mydatatable$Smoker, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider nested `lapply` calls to iterate each *symptom* across every combination of *input* columns with return of a nested list. And the input objects to `lapply` would be the split of all *symptom* columns and all *input* columns from original dataframe.

Since OP does not provide a sample of actual data, below demonstrates with random data:

```
set.seed(788)
symptoms <- sapply(1:7, function(i,s) LETTERS[sample(26, 26, replace=TRUE)[s]], 1:26)
colnames(symptoms) <- c("Vision.Symptom","Voice.Symptom","Delofreference.Symptom","Paranoia.Symptom", 
                        "VisionorVoice.Symptom","Delusion.Symptom","UEAny.Symptom")

set.seed(992)
inputs <- sapply(1:7, function(i,s) LETTERS[sample(26, 26, replace=TRUE)[s]], 1:26)
colnames(inputs) <- c("Vision.Input","Voice.Input","Delofreference.Input","Paranoia.Input", 
                      "VisionorVoice.Input","Delusion.Input","UEAny.Input")

df <- data.frame(symptoms, inputs)

# LIST OF 7 ITEMS, EACH NESTED WITH THE 7 INPUTS
# CHANGE grep() to c() OF ACTUAL COLUMN NAMES
chi_sq_list <- lapply(df[grep("\\.Symptom", names(df))], function(s)
                      lapply(df[grep("\\.Input", names(df))], function(i) chisq.test(s,i)))
```

**Output** *(of first list item)*

```
chi_sq_list$Vision.Symptom

$Vision.Input

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  s and i
X-squared = 241.22, df = 240, p-value = 0.4657


$Voice.Input

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  s and i
X-squared = 247, df = 240, p-value = 0.3644


$Delofreference.Input

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  s and i
X-squared = 289.25, df = 256, p-value = 0.07502


$Paranoia.Input

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  s and i
X-squared = 322.11, df = 288, p-value = 0.08131


$VisionorVoice.Input

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  s and i
X-squared = 215.22, df = 208, p-value = 0.351


$Delusion.Input

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  s and i
X-squared = 218.47, df = 224, p-value = 0.5916


$UEAny.Input

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  s and i
X-squared = 254.22, df = 256, p-value = 0.5196
```